# Django Framework: Python function in views.py unable to find the json file

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to write into a json file through a python function. The python function dumps the python data structure into a json file using json.dumps funtion. 
The file gets created as well as the python data structure in form of json object is present in the json file but when javascript function present inside the python function tries to open and read the object it fails. 
I get the following error: Not found file_name.json
I am pretty sure that the file is indeed present.

```
def func(request):

arr = [[]]
message = ''
arr[0].append('Hello')
arr[0].append('There')
arr.append([])
arr[1].append('Good')
arr[1].append('Morning')
arr[1].append('!')
message = message + '<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="outputjson.js"></script><script>function Hello(){alert(hello[1]);}</script></head>'

with open('outputjson.js', 'w') as fo:
        jsonp_structure = "hello = "+json.dumps(arr)+" "
        fo.write(jsonp_structure)
message = message + '<body><h1>This is shit and you know it</h1><input value="Click Bro" type="button" onclick="Hello();"></input></body></html>'
return HttpResponse(message)
```

I get the error stating: Not found: outputjson.js

Do I need to explicitly tell Django where to look for the file ?

Comment: can you check the directory where the .py file exists? it creates yor file there, as far as the code is .. it is working fine in mine

Comment: @Roshan hello Roshan, are you able to open the .js file and read the required json object from it using the javascript function which I made?

Comment: where is that json file? did you put it in static folder? or the same folder in which views.py is?

Comment: with open('outputjson.js', 'r') as fo:
    fo.read()

Comment: @Exprator I tried keeping it in the same folder as views.py, didnt work. then I made a separate 'static' folder under the app directory and ran python manage.py collectstatic, didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep the js file in the static folder and try something like this

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

url = static('outputjson.js')
```

and in

```
src="'+url+'"
```

Comment: as suggested I kept the json file inside the app folder. ran: python manage.py collectstatic. after that inside the views.py: I entered from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static

url = static('outputjson.js')                                                                                and in the <script> tag entered the src as "+url+". Not found: /app_name/+url+ as the error

Comment: edited my ans, missed the single quotes, try it now  
@jyotirmayaojha

Comment: works like charm, Thanks a lot for your time. I hope one day I get proficient in Django help others the way you just did. Thanks a ton.

Comment: you will bro, just work with it, everyone learns from making mistake, even i do mistakes even now, still learning, you are welcome @jyotirmayaojha

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('outputjson.js', 'r') as fo:
    fo.read()
```

This should open the file and read it

Comment: I doubt this would work inside a javascript function, it would work in python code. Actually, the json object contains input tag id's. I need them to read back the values entered by the user. I intend to use getElementById function of javascript.

Comment: then you might need to do sth like: var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' ); in your json code or simply use JSONResponse in place of HTTPResponse